# Adding Lists to a Visual Studio solution, given a CMP file

Tags: list, content-type

We made changes to a live SharePoint site (added content types, lists, etc.)

Now, we would like to go backwards and generate all those objects in our Visual Studio solution.

Given the CMP, we renamed it to CAB, and extracted the Manifest.xml.

My question is - is this a safe way to regenerate our objects? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Be clear on all changes you made to to live sp site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already made the changes and as you are aware of changes you made in production.  Make similar changes in dev,test box . Write the custom code to remove the changes you made and write the code for adding content types,lits etc . Deploy it and test in dev/test. Its safe , not a problem.

Comment: Should I keep the same GUID for the lists and columns, as found in Production? Thank you so much @Nikhil.